# How to create an instance of anonymous class of abstract class in Kotlin?

Tags: java, abstract-class, kotlin

Assume that `KeyAdapter` is an abstract class with several methods that can be overridden.

In java I can do:

```
KeyListener keyListener = new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

How to do the same in Kotlin?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question shows very little research effort. A simple Google search for _anonymous classes in kotlin_ turns up [this page](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/02/kotlin-m5-1/) which discusses--of all things--how to create the Kotlin analogue to an anonymous inner class.

Comment: I'm also just starting with Kotlin. This question comes up as the first hit with a very reasonable google search. What was very confusing for me was that the KeyAdapter in the question is most likely the java.awt.event.KeyAdapter, which is an abstract class with 3 methods and the simple `val k: KeyAdapter = KeyAdapter {
    println("Hello, world!")
}` wont work. (However I was looking for the lambda syntax.) I think I'll look for anoter question with this exact title, but a better formulated question and link this one to it with a comment...

Comment: @PeterLamberg it's not java.awt it's Intellij plugins API.

Comment: This question comes up as a first hit in some google searches for which the [the relevant question is closer to this so I'm linkin it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672023/how-to-create-an-instance-of-anonymous-interface-in-kotlin/37672036#37672036)

Comment: @Tvaroh Could you add the definition of the interface/class (possibly in shortened form) to the beginning of your question?

Comment: @PeterLamberg I have not that code anymore, I think it's deadly clear anyway.

Comment: See also similar question about anonymous instance of interface: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552299/how-to-create-an-anonymous-implementaiton-of-an-interface

Comment: @brian-roach
I asked this question today at our team premises. My polite co-workers explained to me that I must be stupid for asking this as it "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved". Thanks

Comment: I don't see why this is flagged as too simple. The question is upvoted a lot, meaning a lot of people face this problem. Because of the language differences, it's not obvious whether the first hit on Google is the solution. I skimmed over the official documentation but this question on SO cleared it up.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

From [the official Kotlin language documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html):

```kotlin
window.addMouseListener(object : MouseAdapter() { 
    override fun mouseClicked(e : MouseEvent) { 
    // ... 
}
```

Applied to your problem at hand:

```kotlin
val keyListener = object : KeyAdapter() { 
    override fun keyPressed(keyEvent : KeyEvent) { 
    // ... 
}
```

As Peter Lamberg has pointed out - if the anonymous class is actually an implementation of a functional interface (*i.e. not of an abstract class*), [SAM Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) can be used to simplify this statement even further:

```kotlin
val keyListener = KeyAdapter { keyEvent ->
    // ...
}
```

Please also note [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-and-sam-interface-with-two-parameters/293) about the different usage of interfaces defined in Java and Kotlin.

Answer (score 12):

### In Java

```
private Comparator<Integer> comparator = new Comparator<Integer>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
};
```

### in Kotlin

```
private val comparator = object: Comparator<Int> {
    override fun compare(o1: Int, o2: Int): Int {
        return o1.compareTo(o2)
    }
}
```

But because [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is a [FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) we can take advantage of [SAM conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) and write

```
private val comparator = Comparator<Int> { o1, o2 -> o1.compareTo(o2) }
```

***Please note that SAM feature only works for `Functional` interfaces defined in java, if you need to create `object` of a kotlin `interface` with single method then you will have to use `object` syntax.***

Comment: I like this answer too as the syntax is easier to "get into". Although I aspire to use the other answer's more simple syntax, this one is what I would use at the beginning and did use during TDD.Academy livestream, Episode 36, Android: Text Boxes and TDD #7: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikQAmBNdRRo