# How to create an anonymous implementation of an interface?

Tags: interface, kotlin

I have an interface:

```
interface TileSet {
    fun contains(x: Int, y: Int) : Boolean
}
```

I want to be able to create unions of sets of tiles (tile is a pair of x and y integer coordinates):

```
fun TileSet.union(another: TileSet) : TileSet = 
   // ..
```

In Java 8, I could do it like this:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TileSet {
    boolean contains(int x, int y);

    public default TileSet unite(TileSet another) {
        return (x, y) -> TileSet.this.contains(x, y) && another.contains(x, y);
    }
}
```

So an interface is implemented with a lambda in `TileSet#unite()`. Or it could be implemented with the old anonymous class approach:

```java
public default TileSet unite(TileSet another) {
    return new TileSet() {
         @Override
         public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
             return TileSet.this.contains(x, y) && another.contains(x, y);
         }
    }
}
```

How can I create an anonymous implementation of a single-method interface in Kotlin?

I know how to do it if I use `(Int, Int) -> Boolean` instead of `TileSet`, but I want the type to have a descriptive name rather than just a function signature.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

There are examples in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) for anonymous classes, but not for interfaces.

This is how I created an instance of an interface:

```
fun TileSet.union(another: TileSet) : TileSet =
    object : TileSet {
        override fun contains(x: Int, y: Int) : Boolean =
            this@union.contains(x, y) || another.contains(x, y)
    }
```

Notice that, unlike in the example from documentation, there are no parentheses after `object : TileSet`.

Comment: I get `Object must be declared abstract or implement abstract member public abstract operator.` why?

Comment: @danielgomezrico That must be because your base class/interface (`TileSet` in my example) declares an abstract method, and you should implement it in your anonymous implementation.

Answer (score 13):

I was experimenting a little bit, and I was surprised to find that you can implement **Java** functional interfaces using Kotlin lambdas:

```
// Implementing Java functional interfaces using lambdas
val greeter = Consumer<String> { println("Hi $it") }
val dice = Supplier { ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 7) }
```

But when you implement **Kotlin** functional interfaces, you need the full *ceremony*:

```
// Implementing a Kotlin functional inteface with lambdas is not possible
val greeter = object : MyConsumer<String> {
    override fun accept(x: String) {
        println("Hi $x")
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface MyConsumer<T> {
    fun accept(x:T)
}
```

I wonder why the full anonymous class syntax is needed when implementing Kotlin intefaces from the very Kotlin!

Maybe they want you to use functions instead? That could be done like this.

```
// If you want to use lambdas, define a function instead of an interface
val greeter: MyConsumerFunction<String> = { println("Hi $it") }

typealias MyConsumerFunction<T> = (T) -> Unit
```

Anyway, if anyone knows anything about this, please let me know! :)

Comment: Yes, every time I come across this I get annoyed. I get that regular functions are more idiomatic, but when you're dealing with Dependency Injection Frameworks like old versions of Guice and Spring that don't work with Kotlin functions then declaring the interfaces is overall easier, except when it comes to creating implementations of these interfaces. Sometimes I just create the Interface in a Java file so I can avoid the Kotlin ceremony...

Answer (score 4):

it's possible with kotlin, it's just you have to add `fun` before the `interface` so would be like `fun interface xx`, it's called a functional interface, basically what it means is an interface with ONE function, which is what we usually want

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html