# How to create an instance of anonymous interface in Kotlin?

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin, anonymous

I have a third party Java library which an object with interface like this:

```
public interface Handler<C> {
  void call(C context) throws Exception;
}
```

How can I concisely implement it in Kotlin similar to Java anonymous class like this:

```
Handler<MyContext> handler = new Handler<MyContext> {
   @Override
   public void call(MyContext context) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("Hello world");
   }
}

handler.call(myContext) // Prints "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Assuming the interface has only a single method you can make use of [SAM](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions).

```
val handler = Handler<String> { println("Hello: $it") }
```

Since version 1.4 Kotlin supports SAM for interfaces defined in Kotlin. That requires prefixing the `interface` keyword with `fun`

```
fun interface Handler<C> {
  fun call(context: C);
}
```

If you have a method that accepts a handler then you can even omit type arguments:

```
fun acceptHandler(handler:Handler<String>){}

acceptHandler(Handler { println("Hello: $it") })

acceptHandler({ println("Hello: $it") })

acceptHandler { println("Hello: $it") }
```

If the interface has more than one method the syntax is a bit more verbose:

```
val handler = object: Handler2<String> {
    override fun call(context: String?) { println("Call: $context") }
    override fun run(context: String?) { println("Run: $context")  }
}
```

Comment: `acceptHandler { println("Hello: $it")}` would also work in most cases

Comment: For anyone struggling . i think the interface must be declared in java. i think SAM conversion not working for kotlin interfaces.   if its a kotlin interface you have to use the object:Handler{}  way.   per here:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770 .

Comment: You can do this with a Kotlin interface as of 1.4 - you just declare it as a `fun interface`.

Comment: @Nick I'd recommend adding that as a separate answer, or editing it into this answer

Answer (score 39):

I had a case where I did not want to create a var for it but do it inline. The way I achieved it is

```
funA(object: InterfaceListener {
                        override fun OnMethod1() {}

                        override fun OnMethod2() {}
})
```

Answer (score 32):

```
     val obj = object : MyInterface {
         override fun function1(arg:Int) { ... }

         override fun function12(arg:Int,arg:Int) { ... }
     }
```

Comment: yes if interface is not SAM(Single Abstract Method) this code will works

Answer (score 3):

As of Kotlin 1.4 you can declare a functional interface:

```kotlin
fun interface Handler<C> {
  fun call(context: C);
}
```

and then you can create one concisely:

```kotlin
val handler = Handler<String> {
  println("Handling $it")
}
```

[Demo](https://pl.kotl.in/kii_4xIiB)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer probably is the Kotlin's lambda:

```
val handler = Handler<MyContext> {
  println("Hello world")
}

handler.call(myContext) // Prints "Hello world"
```