# How to instantiate an anonymous class that implements an interface in Kotlin

Tags: interface, kotlin

In Java, instantiate an interface object is as easy as `new Interface()`... and override all the required functions as below, on `AnimationListener`

```
private void doingSomething(Context context) {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        // All the other override functions
    });
}
```

However, in Kotlin when we type

```
private fun doingSomething(context: Context) {
    val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in)
    animation.setAnimationListener(Animation.AnimationListener(){
        // All the other override functions
    })
}
```

It error complaints unresolved References AnimationListener.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an instance of anonymous interface in Kotlin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672023/how-to-create-an-instance-of-anonymous-interface-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As explained in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html):

```
animation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
    // All the other override functions
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Great. When I search in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html, it didn't even touch anything on that. The documentation is quite obscured. Search on the internet also can't find it. The only place to find this is to manually write a Java code, and convert it... Hopefully my stackoverflow question would help others searching for this quickly to find it. Thanks!

Comment: I suggested to improve the documentation in the kotlin slack. I agree that the information isn't that easy to find in the doc.

Comment: That sounds great!

Comment: The documentation has been improved: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#anonymous-inner-classes and https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#creating-instances-of-classes

Comment: Cool for improving the documentation. Look at the number of 'tick' at your answer within two days. Clearly this is a hot question and your answer helps to answer them.

Comment: I dont know why you rollback my edit but can you tell IntelliJ to fix this: https://ibb.co/mHZuqm

Comment: @Ultimo_m sorry for that. The syntax with parentheses is correct to create an anonymous object extending a class and calling its default constructor. When implementing an interface, the parentheses should indeed not be there.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently the latest way (using Kotlin 1.0.5) of doing it is now without the parenthesis, given there's no empty constructor for the interface.

```
animation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
    // All the other override functions
})
```