# Kotlin how to create anonymous class that implements an interface with 2 methods?

Tags: inheritance, kotlin

I have an interface with two methods:

```
interface Human {
   fun talk()
   fun think()
}
```

I  want to pass an anonymous instance of this interface into a method.

How do I do this?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#anonymous-inner-classes

Comment: The answer to this one has an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672023/how-to-create-an-instance-of-anonymous-interface-in-kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `foo` looks like this:

```
fun foo(human: Human) {
    // ...
}
```

You can invoke it like this, using an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions):

```
foo(object: Human {
    override fun think() {
        // ...
    }

    override fun talk() {
        //...
    }
})
```