# JAX-RS how to readEntity response for a List in Kotlin

Tags: rest, kotlin, jax-rs, response

I'm working in Kotlin and want to read a list of entities, but I am getting a syntax error on the {}: "Type mismatch, Required: Type!, Found: () -> Unit"

if I remove the {} the syntax error is on GenericType: "Cannot access 'init' it is protected in GenericType"

I'm wondering what the correct syntax is for reading a list of Entities from a response in Kotlin

```
val path = URL_PATH
val target = getTarget(path)
val response = getRequestBuilder(target).get()

response.readEntity(GenericType<List<FoodSummary>>() {})
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
response.readEntity(object : GenericType<List<FoodSummary>>() {})
```

Check the following for more details: [How to create an instance of anonymous class of abstract class in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516930/how-to-create-an-instance-of-anonymous-class-of-abstract-class-in-kotlin)

Comment: Do you need a specific Maven dependency to make this work?