# Converting getPasswordAuthentication function to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I'd like to convert this block of code from Java to Kotlin:

```
 Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
            }
          })
```

But I'm unable to appropiately convert this part:

```
 protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password")
            }
```

How could that conversion be made?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an instance of anonymous class of abstract class in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516930/how-to-create-an-instance-of-anonymous-class-of-abstract-class-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an anonymous class instance. Check [object expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html)

```
object : Authenticator() {
    override fun getPasswordAuthentication() : PasswordAuthentication {
        return PasswordAuthentication("username", "password")
    }
}
```